# For each post, and each blockquote inside it different style

Tags: jquery, css

Tumblr often has blockquote inside blockquote inside blockquote and so on... and I wanted to make every other one different. CSS nth-child didn't work so I resorted to jQuery [which I'm not familiar with and use stackoverflow when I need it] and used this:

```
 $('.post blockquote').each(function(index, element){
     if(index % 2 == 0) { $(element).addClass('even'); }

     if(index != 0) { $(element).addClass('inside'); }
 });
```

and it works but it doesn't do it for one post then start again, but just continues to the next one and so on. So I tried to wrap it up like this:

```
$(".post").each(function() {
 $('blockquote').each(function(index, element){
     if(index % 2 == 0) { $(element).addClass('even'); }

     if(index != 0) { $(element).addClass('inside'); }
 });
});
```

but it just affects all blockquote posts on page in post or not. If I add .post before blockquote again it does the same as the first case I wrote.

Am I doing something wrong and can you help me right it?

Answer (score 2):

a potential pure css solution is to use the "direct child" `>`  selector: set styles for `.blockquote > .blockquote` and for `.blockquote > .blockquote > .blockquote` etc 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R83YZ/)

[EDIT: given that you want them alternating, you could just [do this](http://jsfiddle.net/cMaf8/) - realistically it is not possible to infinitely nest blockquotes so this doesn't require a lot of extra typing :p. but i upvoted the jquery answer (@mohammadreza) because it's technically less of a hack]

Comment: I know that `blockquote blockquote blockquote`, and so on works, but it's too much code and I can never know how many nested blockquotes will be there.

Comment: try to explain in plain language or pseudo-code exactly how you want a blockquote's style to be modified qiven how deeply it's nested. do you want the changes to be programmatic ie "i want a blockquote to have a reddish font, and one that is nested to have even redder font, etc."

Comment: Every odd blockquote should have different background color and font color and same for even, alternating between two styles basically.

Answer (score 0):

your code problem is in loop by this line :

```
  if(index != 0) { $(element).addClass('inside'); }
```

inside class add to all of blockquote that it's index not same zero ...

u can see result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rYSev/)